# Redirect from www to non-www with using subdomain

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to redirect a URL from www to non-www when user enters URL with subdomain.

Example:

www.abc.xyz.com to abc.xyz.com

Comment: Why you want to do that?
Most of the browser put suffix themselves

Comment: And what was your question? What have you tried? Is this using IIS? More information/proof of research, please.

Comment: What your trying to do?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe:if user enters a url like www.abc.xyz.com it shows security error.And the same thng works perfectly when url like abc.xyz.com

Comment: @Backtrack:if user enters a url like www.abc.xyz.com it shows security error.And the same thng works perfectly when url like abc.xyz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string url = Request["HTTP_REQUEST_URL"];  // not sure the exact Constant name of the header
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
if(uri.Host.StartsWith("www.") && uri.Host.Count(c => (c == '.'))>2)
{
    Response.Redirect(url.Replace("www.", ""));
}
```

thought as was said before, i think it is redundant because browsers do this checks for you...
and you really should avoid being "too smart for your own good".